# What is the word for someone who initiates group social interaction?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example scenario: a youth hostel employs someone to try get guests to be social and interacting. In a common area (lounge), the person may bring together various solo guests into a group and get everyone playing board games.

The end result being a better experience for the guests. The guests then being more likely to leave a positive review.

I experienced this some years ago at a hostel in New York. The social man later said he worked for the hostel to start such social activity. Long after, I saw a volunteer advertisement for the same thing somewhere else. I'm sure in that advert they had a word for the person who starts such social activity - I just can't remember the word.

Edit: Perhaps another take on this is someone who is planted within a group of people with the goal of influencing the group toward a desired outcome.

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted this …

Comment: Yep, I noticed there are here some people with bad attitude and too large ego. 

Coming to the question, is that not an "entertainer" ?

Comment: Cruise director?

Comment: With regards to "entertainer" - I would interpret that as someone who is openly and clearly there for that purpose. In my example scenario, the person's purpose is hidden (but not necessarily a secret). They would appear to be just another guest, but a very sociable one.

Comment: I see you are looking for some sort of "undercover entertainer" and social relationship "facilitator"  :-)  I am wondering though if an entertainer is necessarily someone who has to disclose publically his role ?

Comment: I would ordinarily call this a _social director_ or _activity coordinator,_ but the covert angle is strange. In that case I'd be more inclined to go with _plant._ Perhaps, “The friendly man was actually plant, a covert social director.”

Answer (score 9):

These people are generally employed as "Holiday Representatives", more commonly shortened to "Holiday Reps".

The ubiquitous "Club 18-30" travel company [has a page](http://www.club18-30.com/club1830-recruitment/) detailing their recruiting requirements for such as position.

> Being one of our Club 18-30 holiday reps is a job like no other! It's definitely not for the faint hearted, you'll need to have a great personality, awesome communication skills and enough stamina to keep you going from morning to night!

Typically, these types  of reps will organise parties, excursions and other social activities while imparting their local knowledge upon the guests.

Answer (score 4):

***Activity coordinator*** [Job description](http://www.ehow.co.uk/about_6302179_job-description-activity-coordinator.html)

> An activity coordinator plans and organises games and other forms of
>   recreation for organisations or groups. Activity coordinators work at
>   places such as camps, playgrounds, recreation centres and nursing
>   homes. The primary role of an activity coordinator is to come up with
>   ways to keep the people involved entertained, enthusiastic, and most
>   of all, active.

***Recreation Worker*** [Job description](http://job-descriptions.careerplanner.com/Recreation-Workers.cfm)

> Conduct recreation activities with groups in public, private, or
>   volunteer agencies or recreation facilities. Organize and promote
>   activities, such as arts and crafts, sports, games, music, dramatics,
>   social recreation, camping, and hobbies, taking into account the needs
>   and interests of individual members.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the term *[social director](http://www.mymajors.com/careers-and-jobs/social-director)* (originally suggested by LindaBrammer)

> Job Description: Conduct recreation activities with groups in public, private, or volunteer agencies or recreation facilities. Organize and promote activities, such as arts and crafts, sports, games, music, dramatics, social recreation, camping, and hobbies, taking into account the needs and interests of individual members.

Answer (score 1):

Activity **Facilitator** would be my choice, here's an excerpt from a job description from a UK Charity that pretty much matches your description perfectly:

> "To support the [management] in
>   actively involving people that use day services in decision making and
>   the planning of initiatives which enhance their lives. Encouraging and
>   empowering individuals to participate fully in their communities and
>   come together to enable their voices to be heard and recognised.   "
>
> [..]
>
> Facilitate and participate in activities designed and responsive to the needs of the individual clients. These activities should be designed to promote physical and mental wellbeing, enhance social and communication skills, maintain or increase independence, encourage self-help and self-advocacy, maintain or increase mobility, help prevent the deterioration of mental or physical abilities and include wide social interaction and where appropriate signposting to other community resources

Comment: I remember a holiday as a kid had one of these strange beasts.  Their job was to get us unmotivated kids doing things, without really being involved themselves..

Answer (score 0):

How do you feel about [***integrator***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/integrator?s=t)? It is a broad term that signifies someone who proactively integrates and can encompass various traits (extrovert, comedian, entertainer, gregariousness, etc.)

Comment: I don't think I would get the sense of social encouragement from _integrator_ without a lot of explanation. Based on the cited definitions, the word is more often used in a mathematical sense.

Comment: A click on the link provided will easily clear your doubts (noun def 1). Moreover it's not a mathematical term ('integration' and 'integrals' are) - although it has recently been applied to computing

Comment: Are you referring to this? “1. a person or thing that integrates.” I don't see how that implies this kind of social activity at all. In social contexts, _integrate_ has a different meaning entirely, essentially “assimilate.” It doesn't fit the context unless you use a sense of the word so broad as to be meaningless.

Comment: but then again the link to integrate clarifies the meaning of that word as used here in senses 3,4 and 5 of the verb form with good examples.

Comment: Are we looking at the [same page](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/integrate)? Senses 4 and 5 are about **desegregation**! I suspect that they don't mean what you think they mean.

Comment: well they certainly don't mean anything mathematical. Which is precisely the point I was trying to make. And in this case - as is made abundantly clear in the page you quote from - it only means desegregate when used in a specific context (i.e when this verb is 'used with a subject'). Moreover your comments are equally applicable to the alternative suggestion of 'coordinator'. This word has mathematical connotations too...

Answer (score 0):

**Icebreaker** (or *ice breaker*)

An [icebreaker](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/icebreaker) is commonly considered to be a social device or method the relieve shyness and social tension at a gathering of people.

But I don't see any reason you can't use the term to refer to a person who has the role to do the same thing. That person is, by definition, using icebreaking devices to accomplish his objective.

This is backed up by the definitions in Urban Dictionary:

[Icebreaker](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=icebreaker) (definition #1) actually uses the term in a similar manner:

> The person that shows you around when you're new to a community;
>   called the icebreaker because they usually help avoid awkwardness by
>   starting small-talk. Person 1: Who's that new girl? Person 2: I have
>   no idea. All I know is that Mary is playing icebreaker for her.

and similarly for [Ice Breaker](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ice%20breaker) (definition #3)

> Someone who breaks the awkward silence. Some one who mentions
>   something that has a lot of tension around it.

I don't think anyone would have any problem understanding what you mean if you said you had hired an icebreaker for your meeting or party (unless you live on the Beaufort Sea, maybe). They would probably be intrigued with the whole idea when they do understand.

Comment: I'm sure this isn't the word I saw in the advertisement but it is certainly my favourite so far. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

A "facilitator", as it might be the task of a worker involved in supporting an improved experience of the gaming activity for the rest of the guests, could be a definition for this person.

Comment: This might be accepted as an answer but it needs to be supported with references to dictionaries and other academic sources.